# When to use "fahren" and when to use "abfahren"?

Tags: verb

I have seen many times these two verbs, for example:

> Der Zug fährt ab
>
> Ich fahre nach Deutschland

What are the differences between them and when to use each one?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Fahren* means to drive. In your example, you're going to Germany. This is the actual movement. Note that this is sometimes generalized to a voyage, so it is also used if you're going by plane.

*Abfahren* means to depart. In your example, the train departs. This is only the start of the movement and is never used for planes.

Comment: "abfahren" is also used for taking a junction of a highway/autobahn. "Du musst demnächst von der Autobahn abfahren.".

Comment: I was thinking about adding the information from your comment to my answer. But then, the comment is fine on its own, so just +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

## **`fahren`** is the general verb for **`drive / go`**

> Ich fahre mit dem Bus. - I go by Bus.
> Ich fahre Bus. - I drive a Bus.

If the action of driving is not the main point, you rather use `mit`, when telling about what vehicle you'll use

> Ich fahre mit dem Auto nach Deutschland.

That doesn't tell something about whether you drive it or not. It might be concluded from the context though.

## **`ab`** has the sense of `from / off [ / since]`

So **abfahren** is about **leaving from somewhere**

> Der Zug fährt ab. - The train departs.
> Wann fahrt ihr ab[/los]?

There are not many use cases.

Using **abfahren** with the preposition **auf**, it has the meaning of a **strong affection**.

> Er fährt auf sowas ziemlich ab

Using it in a predicative way, it has the meaning of **exceptional / extraordinary**

> Das ist ja abgefahren!